# Java: manipulate bits in a number

Tags: java, long-integer, bit

I was trying to implement a bit manipulation tool in Java.
I do not want to work with the `Bitset`class.

I am working with 64-bit Long values and implemented the following methods:

```
static final long toggle_bit(long number, int index) {
    return (number ^= (1 << index));
}

static final long set_bit(long number, int index) {
    return (number |= (1 << index));
}

static final long unset_bit(long number, int index) {
    return (number &= ~(1 << index));
}

static final void print_bits(long number) {
    String s = Long.toBinaryString(number);
    String zeros = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"; //String of 64 zeros
    s = zeros.substring(s.length()) + s;
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

I think the best way of showing my problem is the result of this code:

```
>>> print_bits(set_bit(0L, 30));
0000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000

>>> print_bits(set_bit(0L, 31));
1111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000
```

> I assume I am reaching negative values or something like that. I would
>   be very happy if someone could show me a very efficient way of
>   manipulating all 64 bits in a long-number.

Greetings,
Finn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `index` and the`1` a `long` (declare as `1L`) so that JVM doesn’t treat it as an integer.

I also have to note that in `set_bits`, `|=` (or equals) doesn’t account for when the bit is `1` but the desired value at the bit is `0`

Comment: I tried using long, still the same result.
What do you mean by that?

Comment: Hmm how about changing the `1` to a `1L`?

Answer (score 2):

You are shifting an int value of 1. Try shifting a long value of 1, i.e. `1L << index`